# add a vector point on OSM map

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, vector, point

I have managed to show Lat and Lon

```
      function init() {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            document.getElementById('myloc').innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "   Longitude: " +
            position.coords.longitude + "<p>";
        });
      }
```

now i want this lat and lon on OSM map as a point and whenever i refresh the page, I want the point follows my location...

I added this code in my map function itin

```
var vectorpoint = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("VectorPoint");
map.addLayer(vectorpoint);
var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(position.coords.longitude ,position.coords.latitude);
vector.addFeatures(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point));
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a marker layer with a image for easy rendering if you only want a simple marker.

Also you will need to center the map to the desired location. With a OpenLayers.Layer.Vector you can do it easily:

```
  (OpenLayers.Map).zoomToExtent( (OpenLayers.Layer.Vector).getDataExtent() );
```

To make the "follow" thing you will need a timer to update the feature point regularly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only part of the code missing is the center on the point, right?

If the layer has only that point, you can [zoom to the layer extent.](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.zoomToExtent)

If the layer has more than one point, you can [zoom to the coordinates](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.zoomTo).